# SQL Server equivalent of SQL Azure DBCOPY ("AS COPY OF")

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

SQL Azure has a really handy command for copying databases:

```
CREATE DATABASE NewDatabase AS COPY OF ExistingDatabase
```

Is there anything similar in SQL Server 2008 R2? I just want a command to do a simple local copy without any DTS, SQL Server Agent, etc. Ideally, I'd like to create multiple copies efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best you can do is backup the database and restore it under a different name, moving the files to new locations:

```
backup database ExistingDatabase 
  to disk='c:\...\ExistingDatabase.bak' 
  with copyonly, format;

restore database NewDatabase
  from disk 'c:\...\ExistingDatabase.bak' 
  with move ExistingDatabase to 'NewDatabase.MDF'
  , move ExistingDatabase_log to 'NewDatabase_log.LDF';
```

Azure databases are not physical, are only logical and therefore something like `AS COPY OF` can easily be done. But non-Azure databases are real, physical, and you need to take care of all the details involved in a 'copy' operation, like file location and such.

Also SQL Azure has to allow for the `AS COPY OF` to overcome the lack of a `model` database. With SQL Server you can create a template structure in model and all subsequent `CREATE DATABASE` will inherit this template structure.